# How to customize background color of area from picture

Tags: javascript, php, dictionary, background

On my website I have to display all Region of my country, I already have a picture of my country thus all coords for each Region. But I would like to display a specific background according to a check on Region, IE:

Region 1 returns `"ok" => Region 1's` background is green
Region 2 returns `"critical" => Region2's` background  is red

HTML Example:

```
<img src="ai13400_original.png" usemap="#ai13400" width="647" height="436" alt="click map" border="0" />
<map id="ai13400" name="ai13400">
<!-- Region 1 -->
<area shape="rect" alt="top" title="top" coords="136,39,288,189" href="#" target="_blank" />
<!-- Region 2 -->
<area shape="rect" alt="topr" title="topr" coords="286,40,464,188" href="#" target="_blank" />
<!-- Region 3 -->
<area shape="rect" alt="bottom" title="bottom" coords="136,190,286,339" href="#" target="_blank" />
<!-- Region 4 -->
<area shape="rect" alt="bottomr" title="bottomr" coords="286,188,464,339" href="#" target="_blank" />
<area shape="default" nohref alt="" />
</map>
```

[Empty image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec5Xe.png)

[Final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiI1y.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using an html table then an image.  Here is some code to start you off.

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td style="background: green;">Region 1<td>
         <td style="background: red;">Region 2<td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
         <td style="background: green;">Region 3<td>
         <td style="background: green;">Region 4<td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7gPYE/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I sent a picture for example, I'm using a picture of my country (like USA) and I have to customize background for each Region (like Washington, Texas...). So i can't use a table. ;)

Comment: @VenderAeloth you may want to look at Google Maps or another mapping system, and draw polygons on it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_add it will be much easier then using the GD library to make your own images with image maps

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I will use a svg picture, convert svg to png and display it on my web site.

Thank you for your help.

BR.